# Make swagger codegen maven plugin access yaml files from another maven dependency

Tags: java, maven, swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I have an API written in Swagger for which I want to generate both the Service implementation and also the client, and they have to be in separate maven modules.

I was thinking of separating them into 3 separate Maven modules (or submodules of the same parent pom).

```
parent
 +- api
    +- src/main/resources/api/service.yaml
 +- client
 +- service
```

Then in both client and service I would have the `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin`. This way both will be in sync and I will only maintain the service from one place. Other clients can also depend on the `api` artifact and generate their code from the `service.yaml` Swagger API definition.

My difficulty is how do I make the service and client refer to the `service.yaml` in another Maven dependency?

This is what I currently have in the service `pom.xml`, but it refers to the local resources of the service module, not to the `api` maven dependency.

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${io.swagger.codegen.version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>api</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>            
<!-- can this refer to another maven dependency's resources? --> 
<inputSpec>${basedir}/src/main/resources/api/service.yaml</inputSpec>
              <language>spring</language>
              <library>spring-boot</library>
              <modelPackage>com.test.model</modelPackage>
              <apiPackage>com.test.api</apiPackage>
              <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
              <configOptions>
                <java8>true</java8>
                <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
              </configOptions>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
       </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Not sure if this is something I have to do from Maven, to refer to resources from another maven dependency, or something I have to do in the swagger plugin configuration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution I managed to find is to use the `maven-remote-resources-plugin`. In the `pom.xml` of the maven project that needs to expose resources you can put:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>bundle</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*.yaml</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Then in the project that needs to import them, the project needs to be referred to as follows:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <resourceBundles>
        <resourceBundle>group:api:version</resourceBundle>
      </resourceBundles>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>
          generate-sources
        </phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>process</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

where `group:api:version` is the group ID, artifact ID and version of the maven dependency exposing the resources.

Finally, inside the `swagger-codegen-maven-plugin` configuration, the yaml file can be referred to as:

```
<inputSpec>${project.build.directory}/maven-shared-archive-resources/api/service.yaml</inputSpec>
```